# Get square brackets instead of curly in json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, replace

If I want to update object in elasticsearch script, thus I need to send some weird modification of JSON (https://discuss.elastic.co/t/updating-an-object-field/110735/2). I don't really know what language is that or why would they do that.

For example, if input is

```
{"id": 2, "name": "John"}
```

I need the way in javascript to make it

```
["id": 2, "name": "John"]
```

First sloultion would be

```
standardJson.replace('{', '[').replace('}', ']')
```

However, I am worried about curly brackets inside values, so above solution would override

```
"name": "{John"
```

to

```
"name": "[Jonh"
```

And I don't want that. In fact, I need to this inside general purporse library, so I can't just hope this case will not happen.

Comment: `["id": 2, "name": "John"]` is invalid object!

Comment: Do you want to convert an object to array?

Comment: Of course I know it is invalid object. See what I wrote at the beggining and link I left. No, I don't want ot convert to array, this script accepts that weird syntax, see the link.

Comment: You need to find out what format that is and use something designed to use it, just replacing characters is going to break for all but the most trivial cases.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on answers posted here, arrived at final solution, that is a more readable and handles some cases not handled in previous answers (booleans, nulls, numbers, undefined, nested arrays etc)

```js
function toElasticStupidJson(data) {
    if(isPrimitive(data)) return primitiveDisplay(data)
    else if(typeof data === 'object') return objectDisplay(data)
}

function objectDisplay(data) {
    let inner = ''
    if(Array.isArray(data)) inner = data.filter(d => d !== undefined).map(toElasticStupidJson).join(', ')
    else inner = Object.entries(data)
        .filter(keyValue => keyValue[1] !== undefined)
        .map(keyValue => {
            return `"${keyValue[0]}": ` + toElasticStupidJson(keyValue[1])
        })
        .join(', ')
    return `[${inner}]`
}

function isPrimitive(value) {
    return typeof value === 'string'
        || typeof value === 'number'
        || typeof value === 'boolean'
        || value === null
}

function primitiveDisplay(value) {
    if(typeof value === 'string') return `"${value}"`
    if(typeof value === 'number') return `${value}`
    if(typeof value === 'boolean') return `${value}`
    if(value === null) return 'null'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this  it will only change outer curly braces to brackets.

```js
let a =`{"id": 2, "name": "{John}" }` 
console.log(a.replace(/^\{(.*)\}$/,"[$1]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Explicit approach based on input object parsing with [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const inputData = { "id": 2, "name": "{John}" };

const parsed = `[` +
  Object.entries(inputData)
    .map(v =>
      `"${v[0]}": ` +
      (typeof v[1] === `string` ? `"${v[1]}"` : v[1])
    )
    .join(`, `) +
`]`;

console.log(parsed); // ["id": 2, "name": "{John}"]
```

To handle nested objects, the procedure can be run recursively with additional parsing branch:

```js
const inputData = { "id": 2, "name": "{John}", "foo": { "bar": "{zoo}" } };

const parse = (data) => `[` +
  Object.entries(data)
    .map(v =>
      `"${v[0]}": ` + (
         typeof v[1] === `string`
          ? `"${v[1]}"`
          : (
            typeof v[1] === "object"
              ? parse(v[1])
              : v[1]
          )
       )
    )
    .join(`, `) +
`]`;

console.log(parse(inputData));
// ["id": 2, "name": "{John}", "foo": ["bar": "{zoo}"]]
```

Nested arrays also can be processed in the same way, just need to add 1 more condition branch.

Comment: A good approach, however does not handle if nested objects. could do a recursive function from from this, that will generalize solution.

Comment: @IvanJakab added nested objects case